# How do I check whether the user has scrolled to the bottom of a WebBrowser control in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a WebBrowser control to display a webpage and would like to enable a button on the form, but only if the user has scrolled to the end of the webpage.

Is there any way to simply do this without having to override WndProc or something similar?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

And if you just want the user to view one page, rather than browse the web, the WebBrowser control is probably not what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative is that if the user didn't click the button on the webpage, you show an error message, saying that the webpage must be read completely.

thus avoid detecting if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page.